# Why <? extends Parent> is not default behaviour in generic collections in Java?

Tags: java, generics

consider :

```
public class Parent {

}


public class Child extends Parent {

}


    ArrayList<Parent> ps= new ArrayList<Child>(); \\wont compile
    ArrayList<? extends Parent> ps2= new ArrayList<Child>(); \\works
```

Why isnt `<? extends Parent>` assumed by default when using `<Parent>`? I  mean i cant think of a use case in which assuming every Child item is a Parent will cause any unexpected behaviour can you think of any?

EDIT :

a more usefull example :

```
 public static final void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<Child> children=new ArrayList<Child>();
     children.add(new Child());
     children.add(new Child());
     computeSomething1(children); \\doesnt compile
     computeSomething2(children); \\compiles
 }

 public static int computeSomething1(ArrayList<Parent> ps) {
     return 1;
 }
 public static int computeSomething2(ArrayList<? extends Parent> ps) {
     return 1;
 }
```

Comment: @ernest_k reread my question i wasnt thinking ArrayList<? extends Parent> is the same as ArrayList<Child>... but i do think that ArrayList<Parent> should mean the same as ArrayList<? extends Parent>

Comment: Well, you can't add anything to a list referenced through a variable of type `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`, which makes it terribly useless.

Comment: You can create like this ArrayList<Parent> ps= new ArrayList<>(); and add Child instance to that list

Comment: @janith1024 unrelated to my question

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem nice observation i edited my question to show you that isnt completely useless

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You can only add `null` to such a list. But this will change nothing in most cases.

Comment: Well, a list that can't ever have non-null objects added to it would be one of the more pointless data structures.  And if there were no such thing as `ArrayList<Parent>`, but only `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`, then that's all you'd ever have.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem agreed, although it doesnt make sense that the computeSomething1 wont compile... do you see any problem that java designers could avoid by not compiling this?

Comment: If `ArrayList<Parent> foo = new ArrayList<Child>()` compiled, and there's another class, `Blah` which is also a subtype of `Parent`, then how could the compiler stop you from adding a `Blah` to `foo`, which should only admit `Child` objects, not `Blah`objects?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It isn't useless. You can iterate over it, so you could have that as a parameter for a method in order to be more permissive

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem got it.

Comment: Because you would then lose the difference between the two syntaxes.

Comment: @Michael, yes, you can.  But that's not what the question is about.  The question is about having `<? extends Parent>` assumed by default.  That means that you can't ever have a reference of type `ArrayList<Parent>`.  And that means that you can never add anything to the list, ever.  Yes, you could iterate over the list if it had some elements; but if you can't ever add any elements to your list, then how will they ever get in there?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I know it's not what the question was asking. Your comment is a statement which stands on its own. It does not say it's "useless... in this context". It says "if you can't add to a List variable, it's useless". Well no, that's objectively wrong. A parameter is a type of variable, and it makes absolute sense to use the wildcard type as the type of a parameter.

Comment: The OP suggested that `ArrayList<Parent>` should _always_ mean `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`.  That would be useless.  I'm not saying that `ArrayList<? extends Parent>` isn't sometimes a useful data type - of course it is, or we wouldn't have it.  But if `ArrayList<Parent>` _always_ meant `ArrayList<? extends Parent>` then every list would contain nothing but nulls.  _You_ might have a use for such a language, @Michael, but it seems pretty pointless to _me_.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem There's no need to be patronising. I knew what you were saying after your first reply, you don't need to reiterate it. Please read your comment again as a standalone statement and you will see why it was misleadingly worded.

Comment: @Michael Why don't you write your own answer to this question, if  my contributions upset you so much?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No one is upset here except you, friend. I have no doubt that you know what you're talking about, but when you make a comment that gets multiple upvotes and has the potential to mislead beginners, I think it's worth correcting. Fair enough if you don't, but you could easily have deleted it and posted a clearer version in the time you've spent being snarky with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If java did this, you could get polluted lists pretty easily. Let's assume that java did what you suggest, and allowed you to assign a `List<Child>` to a variable of type `List<Parent>`. Then, this would be possible:

```
static class Parent {}
static class Child extends Parent {}
static class IllegitimateChild extend Parent {}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
    computeSomething(children);
    Child c = children.get(0); //WTF - ClassCastException?? IllegitimateChild is not a Child
}

public static void computeSomething(List<Parent> items) {
    parents.add(new IllegitimateChild());
}
```

To get around this, java makes you explicitly declare a bounded wildcard if that's what you want. This allows it to catch such errors at compile time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? extends Parent> items = new ArrayList<Child>();

    items.add(new IllegitimateChild()); // Compiler error
    items.add(new Child()); // Compiler error
}
```

Both the compiler errors above are Java saying "The type of elements in this list is unknown to me (`?`), so I can't allow you to put this item in here, as it might violate the contract of some other reference to this list that *does* know the type." The fact that `? extends Parent` rather than just `?` only really helps the compiler infer information about the *return type* of methods (e.g. it knows that it can assign the result of calling `items.get(0)` to a `Parent` variable, even though it doesn't know the concrete type).

Comment: Thanks! i got it now... so java designers made this compilation error to avoid inserting other sub classes of Parent to a Chilld array list... and they made it possible to use ? extends Parent by forbidding addition... nice!

Comment: As an aside, if you need a reference to a list that is _only_ for adding elements, and not getting, that's what `<? super Blah>` is for.